# SpringDataMongo DefaultTypeMapper has issues with different Classloaders

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I had some problems with the DefaultTypeMapper when mapping from MongoDB to java classes. Everything is fine when running as a TestNG test. But when I start the application via IntelliJ IDEA I get an exception:

`org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate com.example.SomeAbstractClass`

I debugged the DefaultTypeMapper and found in line 150:

`boolean isMoreConcreteCustomType = rawType == null ? true : rawType.isAssignableFrom(documentsTargetType) && !rawType.equals(documentsTargetType);`

The expression `rawType.isAssignableFrom(documentsTargetType)` is only true when the rawType class and documentsTargetType class are loaded by the same classloader. The expression in my case is (incorrectly) false, because rawType class is loaded by ***RestartClassLoader*** and documentsTargetType by ***Launcher$AppClassLoader***. So `isAssignableFrom` evaluates to false and the mapping fails with the above exception.

When I add the following line to my Main.class...
`System.setProperty("spring.devtools.restart.enabled", "false");` 
...everything is working fine.

So, is this intended behavior or a bug in spring data mongo?

Regards,
Sebastian

Comment: Can you please format the code, exceptions?

Comment: Smells like a bug. Could you provide a reproducible sample, like a Github repository containing the minimal code to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Looks like reproducible, if the super class is in jar lib (which is not reloaded by devtools by default) and the subclass in the project classes (which is reloaded). For both classes the classloader will be different. It's fixable using https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-devtools-customizing-classload, however classloader check would be nice in `DefaultTypeMapper#getFromCacheOrCreate`